# DSL syntax with optional parameters

Tags: clojure, dsl

I'm trying to handle following DSL:

```
(simple-query 
  (is :category "car/audi/80")
  (is :price 15000))
```

that went quite smooth, so I added one more thing - options passed to the query:

```
(simple-query {:page 1 :limit 100}
  (is :category "car/audi/80")
  (is :price 15000))
```

and now I have a problem how to handle this case in most civilized way. as you can see `simple-query` may get hash-map as a first element (followed by long list of criteria) or may have no hash-mapped options at all. moreover, I would like to have *defaults* as a default set of options in case when some (or all) of them are not provided explicite in query.

this is what I figured out:

```
(def ^{:dynamic true} *defaults* {:page 1 
                                  :limit 50})

(defn simple-query [& body]
  (let [opts (first body) 
        [params criteria] (if (map? opts) 
                             [(merge *defaults* opts) (rest body)]
                             [*defaults* body])]
       (execute-query params criteria)))
```

I feel it's kind of messy. any idea how to simplify this construction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem in my own code, I have a handy function I'd like you to meet... `take-when`.

```
user> (defn take-when [pred [x & more :as fail]]
        (if (pred x) [x more] [nil fail]))
#'user/take-when
user> (take-when map? [{:foo :bar} 1 2 3])
[{:foo :bar} (1 2 3)]
user> (take-when map? [1 2 3])
[nil [1 2 3]]
```

So we can use this to implement a parser for your optional map first argument...

```
user> (defn maybe-first-map [& args]
        (let [defaults         {:foo :bar}
              [maybe-map args] (take-when map? args)
              options          (merge defaults maybe-map)]
          ... ;; do work
          ))
```

So as far as I'm concerned, your proposed solution is more or less spot on, I would just clean it up by factoring out parser for grabbing the options map (here into my `take-when` helper) and by factoring out the merging of defaults into its own binding statement.

As a general matter, using a dynamic var for storing configurations is an antipattern due to potential missbehavior when evaluated lazily.

Comment: yup, now it look way better. and I didn't know about antipattern you described. is there any other way of sharing this kind of  defaults between functions to not repeat them over and over again?

Comment: If you want to share a "default" value, then I would suggest just having a default configuration def'd somewhere. The common use case is usually to clients take the default config and update it themselves. See http://stuartsierra.com/2013/03/29/perils-of-dynamic-scope for more on the dangers of using a dynamic var for configuration.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
(defn simple-query
  [& body]
  (if (map? (first body))
    (execute-query (merge *defaults* (first body)) (rest body))
    (execute-query *defaults* body)))
```

Comment: @MichalI'm not sure what I was thinking, you don't need a recursive call - see my edit.